# Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { _className?: string | undefined; _enableRegisterUnregisterPage

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-pdf

I am trying to using IntersectionObserver https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API to get the current scroll pdf page number when using react pdf, this is the code look like:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Document, Page } from 'react-pdf';
import styles from "./MemoizedPDFPreview.module.css";
import { Options } from 'react-pdf/dist/cjs/shared/types';

interface PDFPreviewProps {
    curPdfUrl: string;
    options: Options;
    pdfScale: number;
}

const MemoizedPDFPreview: React.FC<PDFPreviewProps> = React.memo(({ curPdfUrl, options, pdfScale }) => {

    const [numPages, setNumPages] = useState<number>();
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState<number>(1);
    const observerRef = useRef<IntersectionObserver | null>(null);
    const pageRefs = useRef<(React.RefObject<unknown> | null)[]>([]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        observerRef.current = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
            entries.forEach(item => {
                let currPage = Number(item.target.getAttribute('data-page'));
                debugger
                item.intersectionRatio >= 0.5 && setCurrentPage(currPage)
            });
        }, {
            threshold: [0.5]
        });

        return () => {
            if (observerRef && observerRef.current) {
                observerRef.current.disconnect();
            }
        };
    }, []);

    const handlePageChange = (page: any) => {
        debugger
        console.log("loading:" + page);
    };

    const goPage = (i: number) => {
        let element = document.querySelectorAll(`.${styles.pdfPage}`);
        if (element && element.length > 0) {
            element[i]!.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
        }
    }

    const handlePageRenderSuccess = (page: any) => {
        goPage(2);
    };

    const onDocumentLoadSuccess1 = (pdf: any) => {
        const { numPages } = pdf;
        setNumPages(numPages);
        pageRefs.current = Array.from({ length: numPages }, () => React.createRef());
        goPage(2);
    }

    const renderPages = (totalPageNum: number | undefined) => {
        if (!totalPageNum || totalPageNum < 1) return;
        const tagList: JSX.Element[] = [];
        for (let i = 1; i <= totalPageNum; i++) {
            tagList.push(
                <Page key={i}
                    className={styles.pdfPage}
                    scale={pdfScale}
                    onLoad={handlePageChange}
                    onChange={handlePageChange}
                    onRenderSuccess={handlePageRenderSuccess}
                    ref={(ref:any) => {
                        if (ref && ref.canvas) {
                          return observerRef.current?.observe(ref.canvas);
                        }
                      }}
                    data-page={i + 1}
                    pageNumber={i} >
                </Page>
            );
        }
        return tagList;
    }


    return (
        <div className={styles.previewBody}>
            <Document options={options}
                file={curPdfUrl}
                onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess1}>
                {renderPages(numPages)}
            </Document>
        </div>
    );
}, (prevProps, nextProps) => {
    let shouldRerender = (prevProps.curPdfUrl === nextProps.curPdfUrl)
        && (prevProps.pdfScale === nextProps.pdfScale)
    return shouldRerender;
});

export default MemoizedPDFPreview;
```

but now the Page ref attribute shows error:

```
Type '{ children: never[]; key: number; className: string; scale: number; onLoad: (page: any) => void; onChange: (page: any) => void; onRenderSuccess: (page: any) => void; ref: (ref: any) => void; "data-page": number; pageNumber: number; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { _className?: string | undefined; _enableRegisterUnregisterPage?: boolean | undefined; canvasBackground?: string | undefined; canvasRef?: Ref<...> | undefined; ... 36 more ...; width?: number | undefined; } & EventProps<...>'.
  Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { _className?: string | undefined; _enableRegisterUnregisterPage?: boolean | undefined; canvasBackground?: string | undefined; canvasRef?: Ref<...> | undefined; ... 36 more ...; width?: number | undefined; } & EventProps<...>'.ts(2322)
(property) ref: (ref: any) => void
No quick fixes available
```

seems Page did not contain the ref attribute. what should I do to fixed this issue?